# Jquery div not centering on page refresh

Tags: jquery, html

I am using the following script to centre the main content div in the centre of the viewing area, this appears to work just fine on page load or page resize, but when the page is refreshed the content div drops to the left hand side of the page.

The problem can be seen here upon pressing refresh :

http://www.twin-focus-photography.co.uk/

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var positionContent = function () {
        var width = $(window).width(); // the window width
        var height = $(window).height(); // the window height
        var containerwidth = $('.container').outerWidth(); // the container div width
        var containerheight = $('.container').outerHeight(); // the container div height
        $('.container').css({position:'absolute',
        left: ($(window).width() - $('.container').outerWidth())/2,
        top: ($(window).height() - $('.container').outerHeight())/2 }); 
};
//Call this when the window first loads
$(document).ready(positionContent);
//Call this whenever the window resizes.
$(window).bind('resize', positionContent);
});
</script>
```

EDIT >>>>>>>>>>>

Ok I have edited now, as per some of the suggestions and now it looks like this :

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var positionContent = function () {
    var width = $(window).width(); // the window width
    var height = $(window).height(); // the window height
    var containerwidth = $('.container').outerWidth(); // the container div width
    var containerheight = $('.container').outerHeight(); // the container div height
    $('.container').css({position:'absolute',
    left: ($(window).width() - $('.container').outerWidth())/2,
    top: ($(window).height() - $('.container').outerHeight())/2 }); 
    }
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //Call this when the window first loads
    $(document).ready(positionContent);
    //Call this whenever the window resizes.
    $(window).bind('resize', positionContent);
    });
    </script>
```

This still wont work on refresh though, if I resize the page......it works, on first load.......it works, hit f5 and it slumps to the left and stays there.

Comment: Try `$(window).on('resize', positionContent).trigger('resize');`

Comment: For me, on a 1600x900 using Chrome, the site is off-center even on the first load. Please tell us your browser and resolution.

Comment: Why are you defining the function inside of the `ready` block? You could define it outside of the block and call the function in a separate `ready` block.

Comment: `top: ($(window).height() - $('.container').outerHeight())/2 });` Remove the last `;`?

Comment: The function you define is not in the scope of the domReady call where you bind it. Move it outside and it should work. Besides: margin: 0 auto and some display: table with vertical-align hacks should do the trick as well imho. ;)

Comment: I'm afraid, there are few style attributes in the css I observed are improperly used. Like the usage of display: table-cell. If position absolute is used for center aligning the div, I feel the same can be attained using a combination of margin-left: auto, margin-right: auto, width: xpx. Ofcourse, for vertical alignment, some calculations can be done and the margin-top can be assigned accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have fixed it, if I change the first

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

to

```
$(window).load(function(){
```

everything now works, even on page refresh.......quite why I have no idea.......anyone care to comment ?.

Answer (score 0):

That works fine. Since you wrote your code in document.ready, it centres the main content after completely loading the page. If you want it to work before complete load, you have to use CSS.

Comment: The problem is that the site does not center *at all*. He already is using CSS.

Comment: If I hit refresh it never does anything and just sits on the left, but other than that it works fine.